# Javascript: Subtract months from a string date using moment library

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Unable to subtract months from a string date using moment library

```js
var str = '2015-10-30'; // date in the string format
var dateMoment = moment(str)
var result = moment(dateMoment).subtract(12, 'months');
console.log('old date = ', dateMoment)
console.log('new date = ', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Can you check in jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/eshwar70/5f10puqa/9 ; It's not working as expected. Open the developer tools and check. I am checking on my browser it is not working as expected. –

[image]

Solution:

Adding .format() at the end of the function;
var result = moment(dateMoment).subtract(12, 'months').format();

Comment: seems to be working?

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: Can you check it on jsfiddle. It's not working:  http://jsfiddle.net/eshwar70/5f10puqa/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But your code works perfectly:
[image]

The result are decreasing one year because you are subtract 12 months (1 year). So 2015-10-30 (subtract 12 months) = 2014-10-30

Comment: Can you check in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eshwar70/5f10puqa/9/ ; It's not working as expected. Open the developer tools and check. I am checking on my browser it is not working as expected.

Comment: it's the moment version. try your snippet here on stackoverflow, work's fine.

Comment: Stackoverflow seems to be working fine. I have tried the same on my local using the version 2.29.1; This is not working. On jsfiddle I have the same version 2.29.1 It's not working. I'm not sure how this is working on the stackoverflow.

Comment: I found a solution, but not seems good. Add the .format() and works on this version:
var result = moment(dateMoment).subtract(12, 'months').format(); 

(if work's, please upvoat my answer, i need 15 reputation ahahah)

Comment: Adding the .format() works; Thanks for the help. ✌

Answer (score 1):

You need go to the official documentation to understand how their internal system works. Here is the official documentation explaining why your code is not showing the expected value. Basically, it is saying the moment object is mutable. So if you are subtracting from the original date, you are actually changing the original date as well. After subtracting, please look carefully the internal structure, you will see `_d` value actually has changed, and you can see the result by using `format()`.

```js
var str = '2015-10-30';
var dateMoment = moment(str);
var result = dateMoment.clone().subtract(12, 'months').format();
console.log('old date = ', dateMoment.format())
console.log('new date = ', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[Moment Documentation](https://momentjs.com/guides/)